# References in a table are mistakenly detected as cited papers

Tags: bibliographies, arxiv

I recently wrote a paper with tables, that contained columns that look like this:

```
\cite{paper1} & explaining a method from that paper \\
\hline
\cite{paper2} & explaining a method from that paper \\
\hline
```

I recently uploaded that paper to arXiv, and saw that both **SemanticScholar** and **Prophy** detected **~90** Bibliography items in it, **while it really only contained 39**.

They both listed the descriptions from the table's second column as reference titles, thus the number of detected references got that high.

Is there any bad practice that I should have avoided with those tables?

Comment: I suppose that SemanticScholar's Artificial Intelligence search and evaluation engine isn't sufficiently intelligent (yet) for prime-time use...

Comment: @Mico yes, that's for sure, thanks. But any idea why it happened? Maybe a "paragraph" that starts with a number is automatically interpreted as a reference?

Comment: My general impression is that AI decision rules -- which may involve "a combination of machine learning, natural language processing, and machine vision", to quote some mumbo jumbo from SemanticScholar -- are derived from analyzing various patterns in "training" datasets. The general hope is that that what works for the training datasets works for real-world datasets as well. The situation you've encountered may well have been caused by one of the training datasets containing a paper that had a table with citations in one column and the papers' titles in the other. Nothing you can do for now.

Comment: There's a link on all of the bibex output from arXiv that says "report data issues". I recommend clicking that and sending them a bug report. Once they fix it, it would display the correct citation count on your paper in arXiv, since bibex is just calling an api.